# How to send a notification to all users that meet conditions?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app with two types of users - managers and employees. Also my app has groups. I have the following structure of the firebase database:

```
groups (collection) -> group (document)
```

Each group contains two collections `managers` and `employees`. Each document in both of the collections contains a field `birthday`. I want to send two types of notifications:

- One to the employee to tell him happy birthday.
- One to the manager to tell him that his employee/manager has a birthday today.

What I did:

```
exports.scheduledBirthday = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 8 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    return admin.firestore().doc(`groups/{groupUid}/{usersCollection}/{user}`).get().then(userDoc => {
        const userData = userData.data();
        const birthday = userData.birthday;
        const userFullName = userData.full_name
        const birthdayDate = pasrseBirthday(birthday);
        const currentDate = new Date();
        if (currentDate.getDay() === birthdayDate.getDay() && currentDate.getMonth() === birthdayDate.getMonth()) {
            console.log("Creating a birthday notification for: " + userFullName);
            let tokens = userData.tokens;
            const payload = {
                data: {
                    notification_type: "USER_BIRTHDAY",
                    user_type: usersCollection,
                    title: "Happy birthday " + userFullName + "!"
                }
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        }
        return null;
    });
});
```

The code does as following: Set a scheduled crontab to 08:00 each day. It checks if the user's birthday is today. If it is, it will send a "Happy birthday" notification to that user (by executing the Android Java code).

As I mentioned before, I would like to send a notification to the manager if some employee or manager in his group has a birthday today. If there are some users with a birthday, it should send only one push notification (instead of sending for each one). In order to do it I thought of keeping an array variable `usersBirthdays` and push `userData` if the user has a birthday. In the last iterator of the loop I made, check if `usersBirthdays` is empty and if it's not, iterate over the managers and send the push notification. But I have some technical difficulties:

- Is it the best way to do it? If not, how should I do it instead?
- How can I know if we are in our last iteration of the firebase loop?
- How should I iterate over the managers and send each one a push notifcation?

Comment: Can you share your datamodel? Especially how are represented the relation between user and manager. thanks

Comment: Not sure I'm following, you're saying that you managed to get your data pipeline working but are looking for ways to improve, right? I believe that you could definetely gain more query efficiency if you performed a [compound query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) based on the _birthday_ field. You can compare the _currentDate_ to the _birthday_ and fetch only those employees whose birthday is a certain day, insteading of grabbing the entire database and searching linearly through it.

Comment: For Firebase messaging, I think topic messaging would be a good fit as users of your _ScheduledBirthday app_ could opt in to a "employees birthday alerts" topic and receive notifications of upcoming birthdays. This, however, will depend on one's own preferences and use case. Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) for more information.